# How can a non-miner store data in the block?

Tags: blockchain, protocol, block

If I am not a miner and would like to put arbitrary data in the block chain, is there currently any method or protocol to get a miner to add it for me?

Answer (score 8):

There is a service named btcmsg which allows you to do this. [Here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=47283.0) is the announcement in bitcointalk. The website is at [btcmsg.staticloud.com](http://btcmsg.staticloud.com).

They use a simple [protocol](http://btcmsg.staticloud.com/btcmsg_protocol_v1.txt) to write and read the messages in the blockchain:

> BTCmsg Protocol v1 (2011-09-18)
>
> Each message is represented by multiple payment which is calculated by
>   the following algorithm:
>
> 1. Two first chars for message type ('01' for md5, '02' for ascii).
> 2. Then the message in hex (python binascii.hexlify).
> 3. Split the long string to groups of 4 hex digits.
> 4. Each group of 4 hex (e.g. 2 ascii letters from the message) is     represented by a payment in satoshi (maximum 0xffff=65535).
> 5. The service fee (composed of a fixed part and a variable part times     the amount of small payments required, minus the transaction fee) can be seen within the first transaction.