# How to store arbitrary data in the bitcoin blockchain and how can I differentiate between a transaction an those data?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, message

According to [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1881/how-can-a-non-miner-store-data-in-the-block), I can store arbitrary data in the blockchain (as the news about "child pornography in the blockchain" tell).
Now I want to store "Hello World" in the blockchain.

Is there a newer website/service that supports me putting data into the blockchain?
And what's the difference between a transaction in the blockchain and such a "message"?
Is the structure different? Why could those researchers even find out that it's inappropriate content instead of a default transaction?

Comment: "Is there a newer website/service that supports me putting data into the blockchain? " I know something in the ethereum platform. According to their whitepaper they allow us to store a message in ethereum blockchain. I didn't tried yet. https://lovecoin.online/

Comment: I know that it works on the ethereum chain and I do also know how it works there. Solidity makes it easy. But the bitcoin blockchain seems to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to these data sources:

- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1023190
- https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/publish-text.py

And of course the "modern" (and cheapest) way is storing arbitrary data in **segwit part** of transactions. I do not know is there ready tool for it, but it is not very difficult to write it.

> Is there a newer website/service that supports me putting data into the blockchain?

https://cryptograffiti.info/ (based on bitcoin cash blockchain)